# ping between Android devices

Tags: android, ping

2 Android devices in lan: 172.16.58.0
I can ping these devices from my PC. (PC is in same LAN)
But i can not ping android devices between them: host Unreachable.
Tell me why ping don't work?

Result of `arp -a` here:
[Android 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdr3D.png)
[Anroid 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRw0E.png)

Comment: show arp table from android device

Comment: @DEADMC, I edited my answer with result of command: arp -a. Please, help.

Comment: @Kahosk, sorry, edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for wireless isolation setting of your router.

There should be option like `Security->Access control` which blocks communication between wifi devices.

Comment: I have router Asus RT-N12VP. Don't see this option.. Can you help?

Comment: Open firmware of your router. From left menu "Wireless". Then from top "Professional". Then "Set AP Isolated" set to "no".